# question regarding Inverse function theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, proof-explanation

I was reading Munkres's *Analysis of Manifolds*. I got stuck on a lemma. I am stating this lemma here.

> Let $A$ be an open set in $R^n$ and let $f:A \to \Bbb{R}^n$ be of class $C^1$. If $Df(a)$ is non-singular , then there exist a $m>0$ such that $|f(x_2) - f(x_1)| \geq  m |x_2 - x_1|$ holds for all $x_1 , x_2 \in C(a, d)$ (an open ball centered at $a$).
>
> *Proof*: Let $E= Df(a)$. Then $E$ is non-singular. We first consider the linear transformation that maps $x$ to $Ex$. We compute  $$|x_2 - x_1| = |E^{-1}(Ex_2 - E x_1)| \leq n \cdot |E^{-1}||(Ex_2 - E x_1)|.$$

I cannot understand what $|E|$ is here  and how this: $$|x_2 - x_1| = |E^{-1}(Ex_2 - E x_1)| \leq n \cdot |E^{-1}||(Ex_2 - E x_1)|$$ happens?

Comment: Try to search *norm of linear mappings*

Comment: Can you please write an answer?@xbh

Comment: If I am right that the book is **Analysis on Manifolds** by **Munkres**, then in chap.1 section 1 subsection *matrices*, the author gave the notation of $|\boldsymbol E|$, and right after that he gives **Theorem 1.3** which is applicable to the inequality here.